# Java Virtual Machine Manager

Tags: java

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Console errors: Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Unrecognized option: -Xincgc

Answer (score 1):

`-Xincgc` is an old JVM option that enabled incremental garbage collection. It has been removed in the latest versions of Java. To start the JVM, you should remove this flag.

If for whatever reason you still need to tune the garbage collector, follow [this guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/introduction-garbage-collection-tuning.html#GUID-326EB4CF-8C8C-4267-8355-21AB04F0D304) to find the flags that work for your specific application.

Comment: can you tell me where to find that?